# how is rails params hash made available to controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameters

I understand the rails `params` hash is available in my controller methods, but I'm trying to understand *how* that happens. Is it a parameter passed to the method? If so, how can we access it since controller methods don't have any declared arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a parameter, its actually just a 'getter' function, that is declared in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb

So calls to params[:something] is really a method call which returns a hash, from which you access the http parameters.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks.